# Vue + axios does not save session cookies

Tags: vue.js, express, session, cookies, cross-domain

In dev mode (express on localhost:4000, vue on localhost:8080) works fine, all cookies saving correct. In production mode i change cors settings and axios.defaults.baseURL, and... client dont save cookies...

but response request contains set-cookie header

backend cors settings:

```js
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL
  })
)
```

backend session settings:

```js
app.use(
  session({
    store: new redisStore({ 
      host: 'localhost', port: 6379, client: redisClient, ttl: 86400 
    }),
    name: '_TS',
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    cookie: { secure: false, maxAge: 600000 },
    saveUninitialized: true
  })
);
```

frontend:

```js
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://my-domain.com';
```

(contain session cookie!)

[image: request result]

(session cookie is missing)

[image: cookies]

P.S. Postman works correctly, and saving cookies fine.

[image: Postamn screenshot]

Comment: Hah. I see you never received a response here. As it happens I am running into the same thing. I can see the cookies in the response, but subsequent requests do not have it. Did you manage to find a solution here?